# Is there a template for creating pages

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I want to create a lot of informational pages for our site but don't want to have to code html for every page. So things like font, where images go, etc.

How do I go about this? Is there an extension I can use? I'm not much for html coding but I can have the right people do this if it takes some changes somewhere in the magento code.

I'm using magento 1.9

Answer (score 1):

What about using CMS sites in Magento? There you have a wysiwyg editor.

Comment: That may be tedious to change designs when we have like 100 info pages. I'm hoping to find something where it's like: text box 1, text box 2, image 1, image 2, text box 3, title, quote. Then we fill in that info and it shoots out a nicely formatted page.

Comment: what about static blocks ?

Comment: So would we create the static block, then create the page and insert the static block?

Answer (score 1):

You could look for a module to create pages. Alternatively, try using custom widget instances to create pages - they would only presents fields / dropdowns etc for the non-technical user to complete in each case and all the HTML is hidden in the widget.

Comment: I have looked and looked and couldn't find any type of extension for this.

As for the widgets, I'm not sure how that'd work. Can you create a widget and give it a url? Or what am I missing here?